# fail to start gitstack after change PYTHONHOME & PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, apache, gitstack

I installed gitstack first(with `Python 2.7`), everything works fine. However, after I installed a new version of Python(3.6), I have to change `PYTHONHOME` & `PYTHONPATH` to the new version, otherwise python won't run.
After changing the variables, gitstack won't start. I checked the log, it says:

> httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
>   domain name, using fe80::91d:dae1:88e8:fbe6 for ServerName

I tried changing `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` back to what they were, and gitstack starts fine. Any where to bypass the settings?